# How can I permanately disable firefox desktop notifications?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

[Notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecmVz.png)

I want to permanently disable these notifications that appear every time I take a screenshot using the built in screenshot tool and some add ons. The only settings related to this are to pause notifications temporarily (which is not what I want), or to block certain websites from sending notifications.  I want to disable this whole feature all together, and I'm surprised it is this difficult.

I have `dom.webnotifications.enabled = 0` in about:config but sadly it does nothing.  Can this be achieved by editing the user.css or policies.json files?  If so can I have the syntax please?

Comment: That isn't a web notification.  That appears to be a Windows notification generated by Firefox.  You can disable that within Settings.  I mentioned that the notification you are asking about is a Windows notification because it notifies you took a screenshot, presumable with the built-in capabilities of Firefox. You need to set `alerts.useSystemBackend` to false. Looks like this might have been disabled due to issues. I would just disable the Firefox notifications within Settings if that's the case

Comment: What do you mean a windows notification?  You mean like the balloon notifications?  What does alerts.useSystemBackend actually do because setting it to true stopped this annoying notification from crowding my screen.

Comment: Mozilla actually documented what it does, but again, it appears to have been disabled due to a blocker (bug)

Answer (score 0):

This is a native firefox notification. It have nothing to do with the webNotifications (which are firefox notifications made by the request of a page you are seeing)

Firefox will use the notification of your OS for this (windows, mac, linux) because the OS may offer more features for screenshots (like share on mobile, etc).

You can search your OS (windows?) settings to disable notifications for a specific app. But there's no option to disable those in firefox.

An option in firefox itself is being worked on https://github.com/mozilla-services/screenshots/issues/5042